# Viewing account balance of an address

Tags: go-ethereum, accounts, balances, rinkeby, leveldb

Is there a way to get the account balance of any given address (address which is not belongs to me) using geth or by using a script which reading leveldb?

Similar to how etherscan (https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/accounts) showing balances.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the balance of any account using web3.js using `web3.eth.hetBalance('eth_address')`

A sample code be something like this:

```
custom_func.prototype.GETBALANCE=function(address){
    return new Promise(function(fullfill,reject){
        web3.eth.getBalance(address).then(function(ethBal){
            if(ethBal){
                console.log("balance of account : "+address +" is: "+ethBal);
                fullfill(rethBal;            
            }else{
                reject(false);
            }
           }).catch(function(err){
               console.log(err);
               reject(err);
           })
    });
}
```

Comment: I don't think you mean `web3.js` as it uses callbacks not promises.

Comment: I mean web3.js.

Comment: As you will see here it returns a `String` or takes a call back: https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethgetbalance

Comment: That is old documentation. I am using web3 1.0.x. check [latest documentation](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html#getbalance)

Comment: eth_getBalance RPC endpoint gave me balance as 0 when I tried with a valid address and the latest tag as parameters

Comment: You need a full synced chain for this. If you chain synced up to block 100 and the address received some balance in block 101. You will see the balance to be 0.